# Add string value to list

Tags: robotframework

My web AUT has about 17 line of text in a table. I have already get each value to a temp variable. And now I want to add that string to the list.

I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'insert'
```

For example, I have the following text line:

```
Text Line 1
Text Line 2
Text Line 3
...
```

And I want to add them to the list like this:

```
@{mylist} = Text Line 1 | Text Line 2 | Text Line 3
```

Here is my code, in Robot Framework format:

```
@{list} Create List ${EMPTY}            
${list position}    Set Variable    0           
${number of row}    Get Matching Xpath Count    //table[@class="GridView"]//tr          
${i}    Set Variable    2           
: FOR   ${i}    IN RANGE    2   ${number of row}    
    ${i}    Convert To String   ${i}        
    ${item control} Replace String  ${table profile name default value} rownumber   ${i}
    ${item name}    Get Text    ${item control}     
    Append To List  @{list} ${item name}
```

Comment: Please also post the section of the code where this issue is occurring.

Comment: Here is the code: @{list} Create List ${EMPTY}   
${list position} Set Variable 0   
${number of row} Get Matching Xpath Count //table[@class="GridView"]//tr   
${i} Set Variable 2   
: FOR ${i} IN RANGE 2 ${number of row} 
 ${i} Convert To String ${i}  
 ${item control} Replace String ${table profile name default value} rownumber ${i}
 ${item name} Get Text ${item control}  
 Append To List @{list} ${item name}

Comment: @RichardHoang As you can see code doesn't show very nicely in a comment, please edit your original question to include the code.

Comment: Well, thanks, I new to stackoverflow, too, sorry for any inconvenience

Answer (score 6):

This is the problem line:

```
Append To List  @{list}  ${item name}
```

The problem is the use of `@`. You need to use `$`:

```
Append To List  ${list}  ${item name}
```

(you also seem to have the problem that you only have a single space between the last two arguments)

Using `$` refers to the list as an object; using `@` expands the list as if you had typed them into individual cells in the test.